# How to configure .NET 7 Web API for deploying to Azure App service

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a Azure .NET 7 sample Web API and wanted to publish it to my Azure App service - configured, then selected Publish button in Visual Studio and after a while I've got success information in Output window.
[image]
After that, browser is opened with my site's address but it returns not found 404 error

I have added Microsoft Identity platform (previously Azure AD) - maybe that somehow affects this, but I am using same Azure AD for my other Azure API without issues.

When I run locally this API is started and page is opened in browser successfully.

content of `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "....onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "...",
    "ClientId": "...",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
}
```

I followed steps in Visual Studio Web API creation wizard
In publish window connection validates successfully
[image]

Also checked this [quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?tabs=net60&pivots=development-environment-vs) - didn't notice anything that I might have done wrong, but it's for .NET 6, not .NET 7, so maybe .NET 7 need to do something differently

It should redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/... for authorization, but it just returns not found

From this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748183/404-not-found-when-calling-deployed-asp-net-core-web-api) found out that I need to manually create a web.config for my API, got this far with creating it, but seems like still missing something

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <configuration> <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false"> <system.webServer> <handlers> <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" /> </handlers> <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyWebApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" /> </system.webServer> <system.web> <httpRuntime targetFramework="net6.0" /> </system.web> </location> </configuration>`

**Update**

Turns out it is **not** working also locally - when trying out endpoint through swagger it returns 401 `www-authenticate bearer`

**Update2**

When I created Web API I selected to use `Microsoft Identity platform` and this code was generated. Do I need to configure AddJwtBearer here?

`builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")) .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi() .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph")) .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();`

Comment: which URL showed 404?

Comment: Instead of image mask your values in `appsettings.json` and please share it in code format.

Comment: @TinyWang after publishing it goes to https://myapi.azurewebsites.net and it returns 404

Comment: When you have a web api project, and test it locally, by default it should direct to swagger UI to list all the APIs. And it shouldn't have a home page like `index.cshtml`. I'm not sure how you operate you api project, but since you said it worked well locally, could you pls let us know when you run your app locally, what will appear after you visit `localhost:port`? I mean if the code is correct, the behavior for visiting `xx.azurewebsite.net` should be the same with `localhost:port`... @Prokurors

Comment: @TinyWang you're right... if I open `localhost:port` it also returns 404. I just created .NET 7 Web API project and didn't do any code changes at all (there is one default controller created by default which appears in swagger page when I start it locally).

Comment: @TinyWang actually when trying out endpoint in swagger I get 401 www-authenticate: Bearer

Comment: Yes, then I think the issue had been figured out.. The 404 error should be the expected behavior. And certainly the 401 error should also be the expected behavior.

Comment: That's because you are having a web api which doesn't have a web page to let users sign in, so the 401 unauthorized error should also be the expected behavior. You should generate the access token first and send it in the request header to call your api.

Comment: For `Update 2` - Yes, we need to configure the  authentication services.

Comment: @Prokurors For your update, I shared a tutorial below you may check it.

Comment: @Harshitha but isn't this doing the configuration? `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")) `

Comment: can my code snippet help you? or any other new issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we create the Web API project, and run it locally, it will redirect to he Swagger UI to list all the APIs and help test the api, but it doesn't mean the Swagger page is the default website, it will only appear when in the development environment, after publishing to Azure web app, the API home page will be `xx.azurewebsite.net` but there's no API or View bind to this route, so a 404 error indicating that there's no API in the application which the routing is `xx.azurewebsite.net`. And normally, the API routing should look like `xx.azurewebsite.net/api/controller/xx`

If you want your web API to be protected by Azure AD, you can take a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview). To summarize here, you need to add Cors policy and add Azure ad authentication into `Program.cs`.

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "mypolicy",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});
builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(builder.Configuration);

...

app.UseCors("mypolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Then here it used some configuration, you need to add configuration in `appsettings.json`. The value of the properties you can follow the document to create Azure AD resource and get them.

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "azure_ad_app_id",
    "ClientSecret": "client_secret",
    "Domain": "tenant_id",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id"
    //I used the same azure application which exposed api and add api permission,so I can comment this line
    //"Audience": "api://azure_ad_app_id_which_exposed_api"
  },
```

Finally, in the Controller, add `[Authorize]` before the controller. Then the api now is protected by Azure AD, you have to have a correct access token to visit it.

Assume you are [exposing a delegate API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#expose-delegated-permissions-scopes) permission. Then the api permission you assigned to your Azure AD application should look like `api://azure_ad_app_id_exposed_api/permission_name_you_defined`. Then you can use following link to use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to generate access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=azure_ad_app_id 
&response_type=code 
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F 
&response_mode=query 
&scope=profile email openid offline_access 
&state=12345
```

Visiting the URL above will ask you to sign in with your microsoft account, after sign in successfully, you will see URL in the browser like copy the value of the code, you need to use it next.

```
http://localhost/myapp/?
code=0.ASxxx
&state=12345&session_state=c71be61a-c4cc-4624-9fa4-fe6c4b2d6b88
```

Then use the request like below to generate the access token:

```
Post: https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=azure_ad_app_id
&scope=api://azure_ad_app_id_exposed_api/api_name
&code=O.xxxx
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=client_secret
```

[image]

Comment: Something's still missing - still, when opening xx.azurewebsite.net nothing happens - i.e. getting 401 and no redirect to login.microsoftonline.com

Comment: hmmm....what you had is an web API... I mean that, for example, if you had an MVC application, you have a home page right? If you add the `[Authorize]` attribute to the home controller, then since you are trying to open a page which is protected, it will redirect to the login page to let you sign in, after you sign in, it will redirect back to home page.. But what you have is an WEB API, there's no home page in this application, you can only send http request to the api such as `xx.azurewebsite.net/api/getUser`, api won't return you a page but maybe a JSON object, so it won't redirect to sign

Comment: let's assume you have a client APP written by React. it will call `xx.azurewebsite.net/api/getUser` to list all users. Normally, the flow should be, client app send http request to you API, since you don't add a bearer token inside the request header, the API though the request is not authorized so the API returned 401 error to your client app, then you client APP received 401 then redirect to the microsoft sign in page... The API project is different from MVC project, it can only give an 401 error... That's why I shared 2 links to let you sign in and get access token.. @Prokurors

Comment: well when I run locally my Web API from Visual Studio I would expect it to redirect me to `login.microsoftonline.com` to acquire token - at least that's what was happening with my other Web API (which I implemented with .NET Framework 4.7.2). I created also a MVC application (with .NET 7) and it does redirect for authentication. I will retry your samples and see if I get some extra info (or manage to get it working)

Comment: Ok... it seems that in .NET 7 Web Api there is no "default" Web application, only Swagger UI. That request is redirecting to login.microsoftonline.com for authentication, but not working from Postman though

Comment: @Prokurors Yes, for web API project, it doesn't have a web page and it can only give the API response or 401/403 error code. You can also take a look at [the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-api) provided here. And you can see the sample had a server( api project) and the client(mvc project) to demonstrate the whole process.

Comment: Now I'm getting the token on client application (seems to be ok when I review it jwt.io), but when I use it to call my Web API I get 401 unauthorized, and I can not find what's wrong.. maybe you've got a clue...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75277630/getting-401-unauthorized-when-trying-to-access-secured-web-api-using-msal-openi